# Working remotely for an Indian company while living in the United States

Tags: united-states, taxes, india

1. Can I work remotely from the U.S. under a contract with an Indian
   company?
2. Do I pay tax to India? If so, what is the rate?
3. Do I need any special United States paperwork to be a remote worker
   in another country?

Comment: Not sure this is the right forum, but some things need to be known before an answer can be made.  Are you a US citizen?  If not then can you reside in the US without being employed?  From where would you be paid (in a US or Indian bank account)?

Answer (score 1):

1. Yes you can.
2. No. Generally taxes are not due in India. As this is contracting relationship, make sure you mention any tax liability in India is responsibility of Indian company. Assuming you are "resident" in US for tax purposes, you have to declare the income and pay tax in US.
3. No